# Jquery .ready() function not working

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2

Actually I am doing zendframework-2.0.3. according to zendframework-ZendSkeletonApplication-zf-release-2.0.3-0-g657a752 I added all the scripts but  `.ready()` not working. in my view page i added simply this code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      alert('ok');
    });
</script>
```

but it is not working but .click() and other functions working. this is the way I add scripts in the layout 
    
    
        
        headTitle('ZF2 '. $this->translate('Skeleton Application'))->setSeparator(' - ')->setAutoEscape(false) ?>

```
    <?php echo $this->headMeta()->appendName('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0') ?>

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <?php echo $this->headLink(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'type' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon', 'href' => $this->basePath() . '/images/favicon.ico'))
                    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/foundation.min.css')
                    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/foundation.css')
                    ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/app.css')
                    ?>

    <!-- Scripts -->
   <?php echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/html5.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 9',))
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/app.js', 'text/javascript')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.foundation.orbit.js', 'text/javascript')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.js', 'text/javascript')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/validation.js', 'text/javascript')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.foundation.alerts.js', 'text/javascript')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.foundation.forms.js', 'text/javascript')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery.foundation.buttons.js', 'text/javascript')
                                  ->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/date.js', 'text/javascript')
                                   ?>

</head>
```

please help me

Comment: Have you included jquery.js file ?

Comment: yes,I added, actually other events are working. I think problem at the  way i import scripts.

Comment: Are you adding the problem script before or after you include the jQuery library?

Comment: Here I use zend framework. so here I include script files within the layout so that layout always load before the problem script

Comment: Any chance we could see the relevant rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      alert('ok');
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

**oh** i see you have the wrong closing tag

you are using

```
<script>
```

change it to

```
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have discovered with 2.0.3 is that if you have `body onload=` in your document, the `ready` function will not be run.  It was run in version 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I just experience the same problem and the reason was i load headScript files in the bottom of the layout, and the script in the view wasnt fired on document ready.

The solution is load jQuery in the head section of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Experience the same problem in php.
Instead of 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js" />`
I changed it to 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score -2):

This method has been depricated.

Use:

```
$(function() {
   // code that will be executed on DOM ready
});
```

Comment: Only the form `$(document).bind("ready", handler)` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. The form used here `$(document).ready()` (using the `ready()` method) is still perfectly valid. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Neither http://api.jquery.com/ready/, nor http://api.jquery.com/on/, nor http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ make any mention of `$(document).on("ready", handler)` being deprecated so I assume it's still valid.

Comment: @pete I was more concerned about it never having been valid. Thanks ;-)